# Activity that happens when the app is launched

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android app and I want to have an activity happen when the app starts for the FIRST time. When the user closes the app and re-opens the app the same screen will not show again. Kind of like an initial registration. I have no databases. Please keep the answer simple as I'm only just beginning in android. So far none of the other similar questions have made no sense. Any help will do. Thanks, J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to use a database then I would suggest using the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) class to store a [boolean variable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) indicating if your one-time `Activity` had been displayed. In your initial `Activity`, you can check this preference. If the value is false, you launch your one time `Activity` and within that one-time `Activity`, you set the preference to true. Subsequent launches will never show the one-time `Activity` as long as the preference value is set properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use SharedPreferences.
Have your main activity check a boolean preference (using getSharedPreferences(context, mode)), and launch the other activity (that should only run once) if and only if this preference is either true or false. (if()/else)
Then, in the other activity, have that preference changed using SharedPreferences.editor().
Do not forget to .commit();
The next time your main activity starts, it will check this preference again, except it will not launch the other activity, since the preference has been changed.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You may use an empty file as marker to understand if app starts first time. During startup if this marker file does not exists it means that app is starting first time and you will perform initial registration and of cource you should create above mentioned empty marker file

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is the solution, you can record if this is your first time or not.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int is_first_time = prefs.getInt("IS_FIRST_TIME", 0);

if(0==is_first_time){

  //here you can launch your activity

  //Save that you already launch your FirstTimeActivity
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  editor.putint("IS_FIRST_TIME", 1);
  editor.commit();
}
```